# Ordering the Terms in an Expression

Tags: output-formatting

Why does Mathematica almost always put subtractions as the first term in a summation (as a negative summed with the rest)?  How do I circumvent this feature so that every occurrence of "-" follows unmarked terms or terms marked with "+" at the same level?  For example, I do not want "-2+a" but "a-2".

Comment: I think the thread: [why `-a+b` and not `b-a`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43581/5478) answers your question.